# How to generate Apk file with Expo's Manage Work flow

Tags: expo

I have project with expo managed work flow , my problem is how to generate APK  , please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command you can use to generate APK.

expo build:android

Answer (score 0):

To generate an Android APK you have to run the command:

**expo build:android**

Then Expo will give you an URL to follow your build status, normally it takes like an hour depending on your projects size and *expo's queue*, and after the build is done you can download it from that URL or on your Expo Build Dashboard [expo](https://expo.io).

Comment: Is that part of the EAS services which cost money or is it free?